# Python 3 search for differences in two binary files

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison, hex

I am looking to write a program that will take the input from two RAW disk images and then open them so that I can find out the differences between the two hex value for hex value.  I then want to see what differences occur regularly so that I can do some sort of analytics on it.

This is the code I already have, I think it should work, but it doesn't. It will occasionally hang on the formattedCorrectly line in hexFormat, but I think I fixed that.  Now the issue is that I know there are differences in the files I'm giving it, but it does not return any.

```
def main():
    print("You must enter a valid raw/dd image of a drive.")
    given = input("Enter path to the first image file: ")
    given2 = input("Enter path to the second image file: ")
    firstDiffs = []
    secondDiffs = []
    x = 0
    y = 1
    with open(given, "rb") as infile:
    #   data = infile.read()
        with open(given2, "rb") as infile2:
    #       data2 = infile2.read()

            while x < y:
                data = infile.read(1024 + 1 * x)
                data2 = infile2.read(1024 + 1 * x)
                value1 = hexFormat(data, x)
                value2 = hexFormat(data2, x)
                if value1 != value2:
                    print("The values at location ", x,"do not match")
                    print("The value from file 1 is: ", value1)
                    print("The value from file 2 is: ", value2)
                    firstDiffs.append(value1)
                    secondDiffs.append(value2)
                    firstDiff = firstDiffs.count(value1)
                    secondDiff = secondDiffs.count(value2)
                    print("This is the ", firstDiff,"occurrence of this value coming from file 1.")
                    print("This is the ", secondDiff, "occurrence of this value coming from file 2.")
                    infile.close()
                    infile2.close()
                else:
                    x = x + 1
                    y = y + 1

def hexFormat(data, location): #This function is used to properly format the hex values being read off the disk
    formattedCorrectly = hex(data[location]) #This created formattedCorrectly as the hex value found at the location given
    strippedData = formattedCorrectly[2:] #This removes the "0x" from in front of the value to allow for easier processing
    if len(strippedData) == 2: #This if statement just ensures that two values are returned, as hex values of double zero and with a leading zero were being problematic
        return (strippedData)
    elif len(strippedData) == 1:
        return ("0"+strippedData)
    else:
        return ("00")


main()
```

Thanks for any help,
-DJ

Comment: "This is the code I already have, I think it should work, but it doesn't." What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does it throw an error or does it just return unexpected results?

Comment: @Cyber (and OP), I tend to phrase this as "What does the code do when it doesn't work?" Often following with "Is there an error message? Does it do NOTHING? Did sparks fly out or smoke come billowing from the computer? Did flying monkeys jump from the screen?"

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that there were no errors, I was using PyCharm and it would occasionally hang in the formattedCorrectly line in hexFormat.  However, I know there are differences in the files, but it is not returning them at all.